# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'slice'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I used `fbprophet` datasets for time series analysis. The dataset has two columns, `date` and `y`, respectively.

```
  date                 y
January 01, 1992      146376
February 01, 1992     147079 
March 01, 1992        159336   
April 01, 1992        163669
May 01, 1992          170068       


  date        y
01/01/92    146376
01/02/92    147079
01/03/92    159336
01/04/92    163669
01/05/92    170068
```

I first changed the date into datetime format by using `pd.to_datetime` and then fit the model `model = Prophet().fit(df)`. However, the result keeps showing me `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'slice'`. Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Here's my code,

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
model = Prophet()
model.fit(df)
```

When I run the `model.fit(df)`the `TypeError`I mentioned above shows up.

Answer (score 2):

Most of regression and classifier methods accept only numeric or string dtypes, hence this error message complaining about your `datetime` column.

assuming we have the following DataFrame:

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
        date       y
0 1992-01-01  146376
1 1992-01-02  147079
2 1992-01-03  159336
3 1992-01-04  163669
4 1992-01-05  170068
```

we can create a numeric column - UNIX TimeStamp (# of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` UTC):

```
In [64]: df['unix_ts'] = df.date.astype(np.int64) // 10**9

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
        date       y    unix_ts
0 1992-01-01  146376  694224000
1 1992-01-02  147079  694310400
2 1992-01-03  159336  694396800
3 1992-01-04  163669  694483200
4 1992-01-05  170068  694569600
```

This is how we can convert it back to `datetime` dtype:

```
In [66]: pd.to_datetime(df.unix_ts, unit='s')
Out[66]:
0   1992-01-01
1   1992-01-02
2   1992-01-03
3   1992-01-04
4   1992-01-05
Name: unix_ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still get the same TypeError after using 
`df['unix_ts'] = df.date.astype(np.int64) // 10**9;
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.unix_ts, unit='s');
df = df.drop(labels = ['unix_ts'], axis = 1)`

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem using Prophet. In my case the problem was duplicate dates in the 'ds' column (i.e. date)

I added

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(['date'], keep='last')
```

(clearly, functionally this does not make sense, but it might isolate your problem)

Comment: Yes. I used `resample()` by date to gather the duplicate date together. Thank you very much!